# Get the variable with the highest value and insert the name of that variable into an input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm adding up values in 5 different javascript variables. What I'm trying to do after this is done is get the variable with the highest value and insert the name of that variable into an input field. What I managed to do is top up the values of the variables and log the value of the highest variable. How do I put the name of the particular variable in an input field?

Here is my javascript code:

```
bedrijfsman = 0;
voorzitter = 0;
innovator = 0;
groepswerker = 0;
vormer = 0;
onderzoeker = 0;

$('.form a.getval').click(
         function () {
         $( "input[type=checkbox]:checked" ).each(function(){
            bedrijfsman = bedrijfsman + $(this).data("bedrijfsman");
            voorzitter = voorzitter + $(this).data("voorzitter");
            innovator = innovator + $(this).data("innovator");
            groepswerker = groepswerker + $(this).data("groepswerker");
            vormer = vormer + $(this).data("vormer");
            onderzoeker = onderzoeker + $(this).data("onderzoeker");
         });
         console.log(Math.max(bedrijfsman,voorzitter,innovator,groepswerker,vormer,onderzoeker));
         }
     );
```

I don't think the HTML for this is relevant for this question so I didn't add it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an object literal that will contain as keys the names of the variables and as values their values:

```
var obj = { bedrijfsman:  bedrijfsman += $(this).data("bedrijfsman"),
            voorzitter:  voorzitter += $(this).data("voorzitter")}
```

Then you could run through the keys of the object and find the key with the maximum value.

For instance, take a look at the following snippet.

```js
var obj = { a: 1, b:2, c:7, d:3 };

var max= Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
var max_key=undefined;

for(var key in obj){
  if(obj[key] > max)
  {
      max_key = key;
      max = obj[key];
  }
}

document.write("The key with the maximum value is: "+max_key+" whose value is: "+max);
```

Comment: This is a decent solution but don't initialize max with an arbitrary number like -100000. Use [-Infinity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity).

Answer (score 0):

I know no way to get the name of a ordinary variable in javascript as string. If the variable names are always the same and if you don't want to use objects or an array you could do it the unattractive way:

```
var varName;
var maxVal = Math.max(bedrijfsman,voorzitter,innovator,groepswerker,vormer,onderzoeker);

if(bedrijfsman == maxVal) varName = 'bedrijfsman';
if(voorzitter == maxVal) varName = 'voorzitter';
if(innovator == maxVal) varName = 'innovator';
if(groepswerker == maxVal) varName = 'groepswerker';
if(vormer == maxVal) varName = 'vormer';
if(onderzoeker == maxVal) varName = 'onderzoeker';

$('#idOfInput').val(varName);
```